# error while building termux build-all sh file

Tags: android, unix, terminal, termux

I have downloaded termux-packages and tried to build the sh file named build-all.sh. But I get these errors.

`Using existing buildorder file: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux-build/_buildall-aarch64/buildorder.txt
Building libandroid-support... ERROR: See /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux-build/_buildall-aarch64/libandroid-support.err`

In termux folder, I have both the files they mentioned. And I don't understand what is this error.
Can you guys please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the referenced file:

```
cat /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.termux-build/_buildall-aarch64/libandroid-support.err
```

Note that building on-device (inside Termux) is not supported, you need a computer and should probably use the Docker image as described in the project README.